# How to do group with match in aggregation mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, yii2

There is no worked if I write match and group. If I removed group or match it works fine

```
$collection = Yii::$app->mongodb->getCollection('products');
            $result = $collection->aggregate(array(
                array(
                  '$group' => array(
                    '_id' => array('city_id' => '$city_id'),
                    'count' => array( '$sum' => 1)
                  ),
                ),
                array(
                  '$match' => array('user_id' => $filter['user_id']),
                ),
                array(
                  '$limit' => 20
                )
              )
            );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it, it works when I put match before group and it works for me.

```
$collection = Yii::$app->mongodb->getCollection('products');
            $result = $collection->aggregate(array(
                array(
                  '$match' => array('user_id' => $filter['user_id']),
                ),
                array(
                  '$group' => array(
                    '_id' => array('city_id' => '$city_id'),
                    'count' => array( '$sum' => 1)
                  ),
                ),
                array(
                  '$limit' => 20
                )
              )
            );
```